# Creating a reusable Angular data input (Mailing Address) component

Tags: angular, typescript, input, reusability

I am creating an Angular 11 application that has 3 different mailing addresses to enter.  I thought I new what to do, but I guess I don't.  I was getting elements with non-unique id warning.  After the first attempt failed, I learned about Single Component Angular Modules.  I am trying a concept SCAM component on my reference application.

I am getting the following run time warnings:

```
[DOM] Found 2 elements with non-unique id #Address2:
[DOM] Found 2 elements with non-unique id #Address1:
```

My concept address component is as follows:

```
import { Component, OnInit, Input, Output, NgModule } from '@angular/core';
import { FormsModule, ReactiveFormsModule } from '@angular/forms';
import { CommonModule } from '@angular/common';
//
@Component({
  selector: 'app-address',
  template: `
<label for='Address1'>{{addressLabel}}</label>
<input type='text' id='Address1' name='Address1' required maxlength='50' class='nsg-input-wide'
  #Address1='ngModel' [(ngModel)]='address1' (ngModelChange)='onDataChange( $event )'
  placeholder='Address 1...' [disabled]='disabled' />
<div *ngIf='Address1.invalid && Address1.touched' style='color: red;'>
  'Address 1' is required.
</div>
<label for='Address2'>Address 2:</label>
<input type='text' id='Address2' name='Address2' required maxlength='50' class='nsg-input-wide'
  #Address2='ngModel' [(ngModel)]='address2' (ngModelChange)='onDataChange( $event )'
  placeholder='Address 2...' [disabled]='disabled' />
`
})
export class AddressComponent implements OnInit {
  @Input() disabled: boolean = true;
  @Input() addressLabel: string = 'Address:';
  @Input() address1: string = '';
  @Input() address2: string = '';
  //
  constructor() { }
  ngOnInit(): void { }
  onDataChange( event: any ): boolean {
    // this.onFormChanged.emit( event );
    return false;
  }
}
@NgModule({
  declarations: [ AddressComponent ],
  imports: [
    CommonModule,
    FormsModule
  ],
  exports: [ AddressComponent ]
})
export class AddressModule { }
```

Part of my app.component.html is as follows:

```
...
<app-address
  [disabled]='addressDisabled'
  [addressLabel]='addressLabel_1'
  [address1]='address1_1'
  [address2]='address2_1'>
</app-address>
<br />
<app-address
  [disabled]='addressDisabled'
  [addressLabel]='addressLabel_2'
  [address1]='address1_2'
  [address2]='address2_2'>
</app-address>
...
```

Part of my app.component.ts is as follows:

```
...
  addressDisabled: boolean = false;
  addressLabel_1: string = 'Office Address:';
  address1_1: string = 'Address 1';
  address2_1: string = 'Address 2';
  addressLabel_2: string = 'Remit Address:';
  address1_2: string = 'Address 1 2';
  address2_2: string = 'Address 2 2';
...
```

My app.module is as follows:

```
import { NgModule } from '@angular/core';
import { FormsModule } from '@angular/forms';
import { BrowserModule } from '@angular/platform-browser';
import { BrowserAnimationsModule } from '@angular/platform-browser/animations';
import { CommonModule } from '@angular/common';
//
import { AppRoutingModule } from './app-routing.module';
import { AppComponent } from './app.component';
import { AddressComponent, AddressModule } from './scam/address/address.component';

@NgModule({
  declarations: [
    AppComponent
  ],
  imports: [
    BrowserModule,
    FormsModule,
    CommonModule,
    AppRoutingModule,
    AddressModule
  ],
  providers: [],
  bootstrap: [AppComponent]
})
export class AppModule { }
```

Now, I would like to have the best practice solution to not repeat the data entry of an address.

Comment: I suggest you look into the ControlValueAccesor interface

Answer (score 1):

I suggest you look into reactive forms, this is ideal for creating custom form controls and generic form controls, as all you need to pass to the child is the formcontrol itself and it will hold any initial values, validations etc. Here you can apply the same custom form control not only for the address, but any other form controls you would have

Here is a sample that will fit your needs. I would stick the address as an FormGroup inside an formarray. Here in the sample I have also included a "name" formcontrol, just to demonstrate that this custom form control can be added for any other form controls you have.

OK, so first add `ReactiveFormsModule` in your app module. Then let's build the form in your parent:

```ts
import { FormArray, FormBuilder, FormGroup, Validators } from '@angular/forms'

// ....

export class AppComponent  {
  myForm: FormGroup;

  // getter to shortened the code needed in template
  get addressArr() {
    return (this.myForm.get('addresses') as FormArray).controls;
  }

  constructor(private fb: FormBuilder) {
    // build form with validators
    this.myForm = this.fb.group({
      name: ['', [Validators.minLength(10)]],
      addresses: this.createAddresses()
    });
  }

    // create form groups and push them to formarray
    createAddresses() {
      let address = this.fb.array([]);
      for(let i = 0; i < 3; i++) {
        address.push(
          this.fb.group({
            address1: [{value: '', disabled: false}, [Validators.maxLength(10)]],
            address2: [{value: '', disabled: false}]
          })
        )
      }
      return address;
    }
}
```

You are using disabled. Above I have added disabled as false, you can define it as true if you want to disable it initially.

The child component would look like this, where it accepts the form control from the parent, displays the field, and any possible validation errors that exist:

```ts
import { Component, Input } from '@angular/core';
import { FormControl, FormGroup } from '@angular/forms';

@Component({
  selector: 'hello',
  template: `
    <input [formControl]="ctrl" [placeholder]="placeholder"/>
    <small *ngIf="ctrl.hasError('maxlength')">Max 20 characters!</small>
    <small *ngIf="ctrl.hasError('minlength')">Min 10 characters!</small>
  `
})
export class CustomFormControl  {
  @Input() ctrl: FormControl;
  @Input() placeholder: string;

}
```

Then in parent component, we just add the child components where they belong (for formarray we need to iterate, name the formgroup, which we use the index for it) and pass the formcontrol to the child. That's all!

```html
<form [formGroup]="myForm" (ngSubmit)="onSubmit()">
  <custom-control [ctrl]="myForm.get('name')" placeholder="Name"></custom-control>
  <div *ngFor="let group of addressArr; let i = index">
    <div formArrayName="addresses">
      <div [formGroupName]="i">
        <custom-control [ctrl]="group.get('address1')" placeholder="Address 1"></custom-control>
        <custom-control [ctrl]="group.get('address2')" placeholder="Address 2"></custom-control>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</form>
```

Here's a **[Stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-gdykw8?file=src%2Fapp%2Fapp.component.ts)** for your reference.

Comment: Thank-you for your response.  I learn Angular 2 by a couple of PluralSight courses.  I had not really used Reactive forms before.  I have been able to successfully ported a form to be reactive in my reference application.  I had a lifecycle issue, but it is now working.  At this point, I have lots of template-driven code and I am not seeing much functional difference.

Answer (score 0):

I had to change a number of approaches for this template-driven answer.  Passing a class to the component worked better utilizing the mutability of template-driven.

```
// ===========================================================================
// File: address.ts
export interface IAddress {
  Address1: string;
  Address2: string;
  City: string;
  State: string;
  Zip: string;
  Country: string;
  toString( ): string;
  getAddress( ): string;
}
//
export class Address implements IAddress {
  /*
  ** Create an empty/new instance.
  ** (Should occur first in class per lint)
  */
  public static empty( ): IAddress {
    return new Address( '', '', '', '', '', '' );
  }
  //
  constructor(
    public Address1: string,
    public Address2: string,
    public City: string,
    public State: string,
    public Zip: string,
    public Country: string,
  ) { }
  /*
  ** Combine numerous address fields.
  */
  getAddress(): string {
    const _addr: string = (this.Address2 !== '' ?
      `${this.Address1}, ${this.Address2}` :
      this.Address1 );
    return `${_addr}, ${this.City}, ${this.State} ${this.Zip} ${this.Country}`;
  }
  /*
  ** toString implementation for class address
  */
  public toString = (): string => {
    return JSON.stringify( this );
  }
  //
}
// ===========================================================================
```

The component is as follows:

```
// ===========================================================================
// File: address.component.ts
import { Component, OnInit, Input, Output, EventEmitter } from '@angular/core';
//
import { IAddress, Address } from '../../admin/classes/address';
//
@Component({
  selector: 'app-address',
  template: `
<div class='row form-group' [class.has-error]='Address1.invalid && Address1.touched && validation'>
  <div class='col-lg-3 col-md-4 col-sm-12 nsg-primary-color nsg-text-right'><label for='Address1{{uniquePostfix}}'>{{addressLabel}}</label></div>
  <div class='col-lg-8 col-md-7 col-sm-12'>
    <input type='text' id='Address1{{uniquePostfix}}' name='Address1{{uniquePostfix}}' required maxlength='50' class='nsg-input-wide'
      #Address1='ngModel' [(ngModel)]='model.Address1' (ngModelChange)='onDataChange( $event )'
      placeholder='Address 1...' [disabled]='disabled' />
  </div>
  <div class='col-lg-1 col-md-1 col-sm-12 nsg-alert-color' *ngIf='Address1.invalid && Address1.touched && validation'>Required</div>
</div>
<div class='row form-group'>
  <div class='col-lg-3 col-md-4 col-sm-12 nsg-primary-color nsg-text-right'><label for='Address2{{uniquePostfix}}'>&nbsp;</label></div>
  <div class='col-lg-8 col-md-7 col-sm-12'>
    <input type='text' id='Address2{{uniquePostfix}}' name='Address2{{uniquePostfix}}' required maxlength='50' class='nsg-input-wide'
      #Address2='ngModel' [(ngModel)]='model.Address2' (ngModelChange)='onDataChange( $event )'
      placeholder='Address 2...' [disabled]='disabled' />
  </div>
</div>
<div class='row form-group' [class.has-error]='(City.invalid && City.touched && validation) || (State.invalid && State.touched && validation) || (Zip.invalid && Zip.touched && validation) || (Country.invalid && Country.touched && validation)'>
  <div class='col-lg-3 col-md-4 col-sm-12 nsg-primary-color nsg-text-right'><label for='City{{uniquePostfix}}'>{{cityStateLabel}}</label></div>
  <div class='col-lg-auto col-md-auto col-sm-12'>
    <input type='text' id='City{{uniquePostfix}}' name='City{{uniquePostfix}}' required maxlength='50' size='20'
      #City='ngModel' [(ngModel)]='model.City' (ngModelChange)='onDataChange( $event )'
      placeholder='City...' [disabled]='disabled' />
    &nbsp;
    <input type='text' id='State{{uniquePostfix}}' name='State{{uniquePostfix}}' required maxlength='3' size='2'
      #State='ngModel' [(ngModel)]='model.State' (ngModelChange)='onDataChange( $event )'
      placeholder='State...' [disabled]='disabled' />
    &nbsp;
    <input type='text' id='Zip{{uniquePostfix}}' name='Zip{{uniquePostfix}}' required maxlength='12' size='11'
      #Zip='ngModel' [(ngModel)]='model.Zip' (ngModelChange)='onDataChange( $event )'
      placeholder='Zip...' [disabled]='disabled' />
    &nbsp;
    <input type='text' id='Country{{uniquePostfix}}' name='Country{{uniquePostfix}}' required maxlength='3' size='2'
      #Country='ngModel' [(ngModel)]='model.Country' (ngModelChange)='onDataChange( $event )'
      placeholder='Country...' [disabled]='disabled' />
  </div>
  <div class='col-lg-2 col-md-3 col-sm-12 nsg-alert-color' *ngIf='City.invalid || State.invalid || Zip.invalid || Country.invalid'>
    <div *ngIf='City.invalid && City.touched && validation'>City Req.</div>
    <div *ngIf='State.invalid && State.touched && validation'>State Req.</div>
    <div *ngIf='Zip.invalid && Zip.touched && validation'>Zip Req.</div>
    <div *ngIf='Country.invalid && Country.touched && validation'>Ctry Req.</div>
  </div>
</div>
`
})
export class AddressComponent implements OnInit {
  @Input() disabled: boolean = true;
  @Input() addressLabel: string = 'Address:';
  @Input() cityStateLabel: string = 'City/State/Zip:';
  @Input() uniquePostfix: string = '';
  @Input() validation: boolean = true;
  model: IAddress;
  @Input() set address( address: IAddress ) {
    this.model = address;
  }
  get address(): IAddress { return this.model; }
  @Output() onAddressChanged = new EventEmitter<boolean>();
  //
  constructor() {
    // static constructor method
    this.model = Address.empty( );
  }
  /*
  ** Component initialization, place all long running
  ** initializations here.
  */
  ngOnInit(): void {
  }
  /*
  ** Events
  ** * flag that the form is dirty.
  */
  onDataChange( event: any ): boolean {
    this.onAddressChanged.emit( true );
    return false;
  }
  //
}
// ===========================================================================
```

The Input of uniquePostfix is used to make the DOM happy.
Usage as follows:

```
<app-address
  [disabled]='!editable'
  [uniquePostfix]='companyUniquePostfix'
  [address]='model.CompanyAddress'
  (onAddressChanged)='onFormChanged( $event )'>
</app-address>
<app-address
  [disabled]='!editable'
  [addressLabel]='remitAddressLabel'
  [uniquePostfix]='remitUniquePostfix'
  [validation]='remitValidation'
  [address]='model.RemitAddress'
  (onAddressChanged)='onFormChanged( $event )'>
</app-address>
```